# Generate grid with tiles attributes from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm generating grid of tiles with jQuery and now I wanna give them attributes which I wanna get from array and later from server. It would be good to do this without giving an ID for any tile. Any ideas how to do this?

```js
function createGrid() {
    myGrid = $('<tileBox>');
    var rows = 1;
    var cols = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo(myGrid);
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            $('<tile>').appendTo(row);
        }
    }
    myGrid.appendTo("#container");
}
```

```css
tile{
  /* width: 50px;
  height: 50px; */
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 15;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MetroUI.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MetroUI.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', createGrid); 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.attr` but if you want reference to a specific element, I think ids may be best.  But if you simply want to iterate through an array fetched by ajax, then you could find the container and then loop through it, modifying it's elements.

Comment: It makes sense, buuuut how to change tile's style (about modifying elements)? For example I have new color in array and I want to replace original tile's color with this.

Comment: Use `.style`, or `.attr` or `.addClass` in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So if your making a grid in your example its 1 row 10 columns then you would just store the attributes in an array marker 0 being grid 1. So in your array of data (or server data) you need 10 objects. If the grid was 4x4 16 objects.

```
var grid=[{name:"grid1"},{name:"grid2"},{name:"grid3"},{name:"grid4"}];
```

I have used name for my attribute it could be anything, my grids being named grid1,grid2 are not id's they are just values they could be a,b,c,d...

All you now do is add the attributes as you draw your grid like so;

I'm using your code for simplicity:

```
// i use a marker to step through my array of data!
var gridMarker=0;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var row = $('<tr>').appendTo(myGrid);
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      // replace the hash on your tile to add my array.name data  
      $('<tile data-name="#">'.replace("#",grid[marker].name).appendTo(row);
      // increment my marker;  
      marker++;
    }
}
```

You could speed things up and improve the whole thing if you used a client side template engine. If you google jquery templates or just javascript template you will find a number of them, the docs are self explanatory.

Comment: Why can't I use something like this? I simply added your code to mine and I think it should work now. `code`function createGrid() {
    myGrid = $('<tileBox>');
    var rows = 1;
    var cols = 4;
    var grid=[{name:"grid1"},{name:"grid2"},{name:"grid3"},{name:"grid4"}];
    var gridMarker=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo(myGrid);
        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
       $('<tile data-name="#">'.replace("#",grid[marker].name).appendTo(row));
      marker++;
        }
    }